# Simple Website not building

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP .Net programming. I know C,C++ and C#. I have got the book  named ASP.Net 4.5.1 in C# and VB by Imar Spaanjaars.

I have  got Visual Studio 2013 ultimate installed as well.

What is bothering me ?
I did exactly as the author told and I getting the errors when building
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kantg.jpg). See screen shot.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: As the errors say, you are missing references. I think you didn't make the right type of project to start with, you did File -> New -> Website instead of File -> New -> Project and from there Visual C# -> ASP.NET Web Aplication.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your project misses some dll in the project bin folder. Could you please check? 
Otherwise it may be that you need to configure Nuget, in order to download automatically those missing packages.